# Do supertranslations act in a physically nontrivial way?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, asymptotics

I'm currently reading arXiv: [1703.05448 [hep-th]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448). In this question, I'm interested in a statement made on page 67 of the pdf (76 of the printed book, if you prefer to check in it). There, the author says

> Supertranslations transform one geometry into a new, physically inequivalent geometry, despite the fact that they are diffeomorphisms. To see this, consider a solution where an outgoing pulse of gravitational or electromagnetic waves crosses the south pole of $\mathcal{I}^+$, and another pulse crosses the north pole of $\mathcal{I}^+$, both at retarded time $u = 100$. Now supertranslate this solution with a function $f(z,\bar{z})$ that has the property that $f(\text{south pole})=100$ and $f(\text{north pole})=0$. The new solution now has one outgoing pulse at the north pole only at $u = 100$ and one at the south pole only at $u = 200$. The outgoing data are measurably changed by the supertranslation.

I disagree that there is a physical difference between these two situations. This example seems to me like an expression of the relativity of simultaneity, which can be attained by a mere Lorentz boost. Hence, this example does not seem to give a good argument for supertranslations to actually act physically on the spacetime.

My question is then: do supertranslations act in a physically nontrivial way on the spacetime or on the fields upon it, or do they behave just like any other regular diffeomorphism? A satisfactory answer could debunk the argument I just gave concerning the relativity of simultaneity, or could give a completely different example.

Comment: Would you say that the state of a moving object is physically distinct from that of a stationary object? These two states are certainly related by boosts, which is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @A.V.S. - Of course, that's true for all transformations. If everything in the system (observer included) is transformed, nothing changes. That's never what we mean by symmetry transformation. What I'm talking about is comparing an object and a boosted object (universe, if you prefer) while keeping the observer unchanged. Those two states are indeed related by a diffeomorphism, but are clearly distinguishable.

Comment: @A.V.S. - Boosts are asymptotic symmetries of generic AF spacetimes (as are supertranslations). That is the whole context of this question in the first place.

Comment: @Prahar Thanks for the discussion. I wrote an answer explaining my viewpoint (and deleted my earlier comments).

Answer (score 0):

I am also not impressed with Strominger's argument. Yes, the data have been changed by supertranslation, yet this alone does not make the result of supertranslation transformation “physically inequivalent”. Consider for example two data plots differing only in colors of plot points. Data on those plots are certainly different, but are they *physically different*? The answer, of course,  depends on what the colors represents: is there a physical reason for the colors or is it a result of circumstances beyond physics?

To delve deeper let us recap what are asymptotic symmetries (AS). To be precise AS are not strictly diffeomorphisms, they are *equivalence classes* of diffeomorphisms i.e. diffeomorphisms preserving boundary conditions (BC) modulo trivial diffeomorphisms (that is diffeomorphisms acting trivially on BC). Thus while AS act on spacetime they are specified by a set of BC. To quantify the action of a specific AS transformation we cannot act with *just* one diffeomorphism on spacetime and “keep observer unchanged” as has been suggested in the comments. There is no guarantee that diffeomorphism chosen from a given equivalence class would be able to “keep” any specific observer. For example if spacetime contains black holes there would be trivial diffeomorphisms that place that black hole in front of any given observer thus making their observations moot and we can combine such trivial diffeomorphism with representative of any equivalence class. Instead we need to keep track of what all those diffeomorphisms from this class did to more and more distant (in the limit, asymptotic) regions of spacetime. For a more concrete perspective, in the Bondi–Sachs formalism whatever happens with the solution at any finite value of $r$ is irrelevant, only the asymptotics matter and those are what define that set of BC.

So the answer on “physicality” of supertranslations hinges on the nature of relevant BC. And if the  spacetime within our discussion is considered “god given” and as physical as it gets, at a first glance BC seem to be the “work of man”, a purely artificial construct: We chose one set of BC, we can choose another! But if we look closer, we find that requirements for BC are quite serious: if BC are too restrictive there would be too few solutions to be of much use, if BC are too lax it would be difficult to construct integrable conserved quantities. So while there seem to be no universal method of constructing BC once a consistent set of BC is given that contains large class of solutions and leads to a rich algebra of conserved quantities it certainly merits investigation.
And while the BMS symmetry may not be *the* group of AS it is certainly useful.

To me supertranslations are physical not because once applied they correspond to changed ingoing/outgoing data but rather because the passage of gravitational waves when witnessed by asymptotic observers would correspond to some specific supertranslation. After the gravitational wave passed, the observers do not return to their original position and instead remain displaced (memory effect) and this displacement can be interpreted as the change in supertranslation field. And the accompanied change in supertranslation charges are quite naturally interpreted as charges being carried away by the GW. In this regard supertranslation field is somewhat analogous to the role of energy in nonrelativistic mechanics: while its actual value can be chosen arbitrarily its change through physical interaction is measurable.

> This example seems to me like an expression of the relativity of simultaneity, which can be attained by a mere Lorentz boost.

I actually think that relativity of simultaneity is actual *physical* property. And Lorentz boosts (and the whole of Lorentz group) do form part of BMS in addition to supertranslations. Only supertranslations readjust time based on arbitrary function of celestial sphere. This also tells us something about “effective causal structure” as experienced by observers living on null infinity: observers at different points of celestial sphere are causally disconnected, the geometry of null infinity is that of Carrollian manifold.